# Modal image with download link

Tags: image, download, modal-dialog

I have a modal image that when clicked, will open full-screen with the text displayed from the alt tag in the image. I grabbed the code off another site so need to change it to add a download link within the modal so when the link is clicked it will download a file. Is this possible in the below code?

Code below:

```
    <img id="myImg1" src="test.png" alt="Hello" width="95" height="146">

<!-- The Modal -->
<script
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
 <span class="close">x</span>
 <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
<div id="caption">
<div id="caption1"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg1');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption1");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please mention what is the error or problem you are facing . we will surely help you out  :)

Comment: There's no error. Currently what's there works but I now want to add a download link inside the modal with the image and text, so when the image pops up onscreen a download link is available to download a file

Comment: ok i see so basicallly you need a download link on your modal ?

Comment: i inserted a anchor tag in your code . you also need a server side code so that a user can really download it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<a href="#">Download</a>
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")\[0\];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my page as to the above but there's no download link I can see. The image and the alt text is displayed as normal, and the X to close out of the modal but I can't see a download link anywhere. I'd upload a screeshot but I don't know how to sorry to an answer.

Comment: This is where I grabbed the script from:

Comment: Thank you so much, that's worked! Now how would I go and style the download link? I would like it displayed on the right hand side just underneath the (X) close button and change the colour to white? Just this download link I would like to style so it doesn't affect the rest of my download links on another page?

Comment: Or move the download link to in the middle of the picture and to either above or below it?

Comment: Sorry for so many questions. But there's another issue. If I have one picture, the download link shows up fine, however if I have multiple pictures on the same page, the modal doesn't pop up now with the download link added.

Comment: <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
 <a href="#">Download</a>
  <span class="close">x</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
 <div id="caption">
  <div id="caption1">
 </div>
    </div>

Comment: Sorry disregard the above, it's rubbish, posted by accident. 2 Questions I'd like clarified to avoid confusion. 1. How do I have multiple images side by side and when clicked each one will have the same behaviour as the other one, don't want it in a slide show, just click on the image and the image and alt text pops up? 2. How do I style the download link so it appears above or below the picture when clicked?

Comment: I fixed the multiple images issue, but can't get the download link to work. When I click on it, the hover state changes but nothing happens, it's like a dead link but I've referenced a file and it works out of the modal but not within.

Comment: More playing and testing, it appears that the download link exists for all images and is not unique to individual images. How would I do a unique download link for each image?

Comment: for unique download option you will require unique modal for that image .

Comment: <div id="myModal" class="modal"> ..........

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); ...

change the id for unique modal

Comment: and if you want to work only with one modal than you will require a back-end code...thanx for the tick ..You deserve a upvote :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that, still trying to understand everything. Would you be able to write the code for me based on the above that you did for me? I was able to figure out how to do multiple images just by changing the <div id="myModal1" class="modal">....</div>, <div id="myModal2" class="modal"> and the script that runs the modal but I can't figure out how to make the download link work for each image.

Comment: download link will work only if you use back-end . You need to know  PhP , ruby etc . What you are doing is front end .

Comment: Well I'm running this web page on a php server if that helps?

Comment: I don't have any php code sorry, I'm just using wampserver to run the website. I have no coding knowledge at all, that's why this is all a bit high level for me.

Comment: download will only work after you apply  php or any back-end to it.
You can leave it to users browser for now for downloading. You can apply php code after you learn it.:)