# Link within a modal to download or go to a large version of the image

Tags: javascript, image, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Currently trying to make a photo gallery similar to google photos set up. I am running into issues because my pictures are pretty large - 15mb~ and people with slow connections won't have a good user experience.

I have a placeholder image that is displayed until the fullsize image loads, but I am running into issues if you right click and view fullsize image it links to the small image file.

But mainly I just want to create a link within my modal to take them to the fullsize image.

https://jsfiddle.net/mikemaer/ghc9o1v6/10/

```
`function onClick(element) {
        document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
        document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
    }

    (() => {
        'use strict';
        // Page is loaded
        const objects = document.getElementsByClassName('asyncImage');
        Array.from(objects).map((item) => {
            // Start loading image
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = item.dataset.src;
            // Once image is loaded replace the src of the HTML element
            img.onload = () => {
                item.classList.remove('asyncImage');
                return item.nodeName === 'IMG' ?
                    item.src = item.dataset.src :
                    item.style.thumbnail = `url(${item.dataset.src})`;
            };
        });
    })();`
```

I just used a random image without the placeholder image for an example.

The only relevant post I found was this --- [Modal image with download link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031521/modal-image-with-download-link) and the only real response that seemed semi correct was that you need to implement PHP.

I am very new to this if anyone has some advice it would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: The popup should show fullsize image right?

Comment: No sorry the popup and the image that loads in after the placeholder is max 1920x1080 and then the fullsize image which is 2/3x bigger would be the download link

Comment: I can't understand, can you explain clearly?

Comment: the image in the popup will be around 1mb - and I want the download link to be the full size raw image which is around 15mb

Comment: Ok, understand now, it should work like this right? https://storage.googleapis.com/support-forums-api/attachment/message-39096377-17155252304883457653.png

Comment: Kind-of but the link would lead to a different file than the one being displayed

Comment: Check here https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/39060937?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an only way to do this i guess, If you get better solution you can use it. please check here.

```
<img src="https://edmullen.net/test/rc.jpg" data-src="img/canon (1).JPG" onclick="onClick(this)" class="mm-hover-opacity asyncImage" oncontextmenu="window.open('https://edmullen.net/test/rc.jpg', '_blank')">
```

Here you can replace `oncontextmenu="window.open('https://edmullen.net/test/rc.jpg', '_blank')` High-quality image file URL

I mean `oncontextmenu="window.open('img/canon (1).JPG', '_blank')`

Comment: So when I right click on the image it will instantly open up whatever i place inside the () in a new tab? Genius! That is a solution that I will use for now, I will keep searching for a way to make a button within the modal that does the same thing just for functionality. Thank you for teaching me this :D